# EventDrop and EventResize not working on ROR4

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

i have this js.coffee
http://pastebin.com/U3Mc8ZW6

this controller
http://pastebin.com/chrYLga6

and this Model
http://pastebin.com/n9fjt7ds

When i resize or drag an event, the database is not updated.

The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'update'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: gem 'jquery-rest-rails'

Comment: I have the same problem but already have this gem installed. If you run into problems again (and I think this may be an intermittent bug) would you mind posting back here?

Comment: @SaroVin can you guide me to achieve the same task??